# viewWillLayoutSubviews and rotation

Tags: ios, rotation

In my app I am positioning all of my views in viewWillLayoutSubviews.  Recently I been asked to make the app handle all orientations.  I figured that would be simple because I was using

`CGRect rotatedFrame = [self.view convertRect:self.view.frame fromView:nil];`

Which would return a frame that matches the device current orientation.  Unfortunately I found that this does not work for all situations.  Namely if I present a modal viewcontroller, rotate it to landscape and then dismiss it, the parent viewcontroller 'rotatedFrame' is not what I expected.  This causes my view be layout incorrectly.

Is there a way to get the correct orientation frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that instead of putting `nil` for the `fromView:` I use the parent of the view that it works as expected.

`CGRect rotatedFrame = [self.view convertRect:self.view.frame fromView:self.view.superview];`